# How can I sort a 2D array of pairs sorted by its second type (int)?

Tags: c++

I have a 2D array of pairs which counts the number of times a word appeared. I want to sort it so that words that appear the most come first.

Example 2D Array (before sort):

```
hello  3
jack   5
the    2
fish  10
```

---

After sort:

```
fish  10
jack   5
hello  3
the    2
```

Comment: [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). Always use `std::sort` unless you have very specific requirements on the sorting algorithm used. You can pass e.g. a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) for custom ordering using the second value of the pair.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your `std::array<std::pair<std::string,int>,4>` and want to sort on the `int` value descending (e.g. the `.second` member of the pair), you can simply write a lamba function that takes two `std::pair<std::string,int>& a` (and `b`) pairs and then returns `true` if `a` sorts before `b` for your descending sort by the `.second` member of the pair.

For example you could write a lambda named `how` to tell `std::sort` how to sort the array of pairs. It could be written as:

```cpp
  /* lambda to sort std::pair<std::string,int> by .second descending */
  auto how = [](std::pair<std::string,int>& a,
                std::pair<std::string,int>& b) {
    return a.second > b.second;
  };
```

By returning `true` when `a.second` is larger than `b.second`, you define a descending sort based on the `.second` member of your std::pair.

A short example would be:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <string>

int main (void) {
  
  /* std::pair is an aggregate and its initializer must be {..} enclosed
   * std::array { std::pair { pairs {"s", n}, {"t", m}, ... } }
   */
  std::array<std::pair<std::string,int>,4> arr {{ {"hello", 3},
                                                  {"jack", 5},
                                                  {"the", 2},
                                                  {"fish", 10} }};
  
  /* lambda to sort std::pair<std::string,int> by .second descending */
  auto how = [](std::pair<std::string,int>& a,
                std::pair<std::string,int>& b) {
    return a.second > b.second;
  };
  
  /* sort arr */
  std::sort (arr.begin(), arr.end(), how);
  
  /* output result */
  for (const auto& p : arr)
    std::cout << p.first << " " << p.second << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/sort_array_pairs
fish 10
jack 5
hello 3
the 2
```

---

**Using a Class/Struct Template overload of `operator()`**

Is another option that allows you to provide a class implementation that does the same thing as using the lambda above for `std::sort`. Instead of the lamba you can write a short struct that overloads `bool operator()` and returns the same comparison, using the `struct` type with `std::sort`.

For example:

```cpp
  struct {
    bool operator() (std::pair<std::string,int>& a,
                     std::pair<std::string,int>& b) const {
      return a.second > b.second;
    }
  } sort_desc_2nd;
```

And your call to `std::sort` would be:

```cpp
  std::sort (arr.begin(), arr.end(), sort_desc_2nd);
```

(same result)

I'm not sure if one is preferred over the other, just know you have options in how you define your custom sort and choose the method that fits your circumstance the best. Examples for both are shown at [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) and [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) as @SomeProgrammerDude provided in the comment.